# VBA Object for Status Bar Metrics

Tags: excel, vba, count, statusbar

I'm trying to return the filtered row count that appears in the Excel Status Bar at the bottom of the Excel Window.  The "76 of 4008" that shows up at the bottom of the screen when I filter a range.

How do I call those numbers?

My thought is 'Why recalculate when Excel already did?'

In the end, I want a macro to filter, save the visible row count in a variable, filter differently, save the visible row count in a variable, then show a message box returning both row counts.  I have everything else written, but can't find the object where the Excel Status Bar metrics (Count, Sum, Average, etc.) are stored.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am able to delete only visible rows using this:
   ` lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`
   ` If lr > 1 Then`
        `Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`
    `End If`
So, I tried to re work it in this way:

Comment: Why don't you just use `.Range("A1", .cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count` ? if you do that, you get the number of rows

Comment: When I do that,
    `lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`
    `If lr > 1 Then`
       `RowCount = Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count`
   `End If`
it returns 1, every time, despite showing 780 of 30093 in the Excel Status Bar

Answer (score 1):

You need to count from the next row after your header, so if your header is in A1 and all the cells in the column A are filled you can do this:

```
Sub VisibleRows()

    Dim RowsStore As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
         RowsStore = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to keep several counts and you always filter the same column you could use an array to store the results and a loop to go through the criterias of your filters.